# Assign color to each value of numeric vector ranging from negative to positive

Tags: r, colors

I have a numeric vector

```
vector <- c(4.80,1.09,33.40,0.00,11.63,1.86,2.22,-10.95,-3.09,0.00,2.38,0.00,
            43.46,12.55,-49.51,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.72,0.00,0.00,-0.74,0.00,-5.79)
```

ranging from -49.510 to 43.460.

I would like to assign to each number a color from this palette

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(colors=c("#FF0000", "#FFFF00"))
```

ranging from "red" to "yellow". I want 0.00 to be assigned the central value of the palette and the other numbers a palette value toward "#FF0000" or "#FFFF00" - respectively for negative and positive number - proportional to their distance from 0.00.

Is that possible? Should I divide my vector into intervals?

NOTE: I am using `plot()`

Comment: Are you using base plotting? Take a look at `ggplot2`: `ggplot(data.frame(x=seq_along(vector), y=1, col=vector), aes(x, y, colour=col)) + geom_point(size=8)`, will that suffice?

Comment: I am not using ggplot. I am using base plot.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answer but this is what I tried.

```
    x<-c(4.80,1.09,33.40,0.00,11.63,1.86,2.22,-10.95,-3.09,0.00,2.38,0.00,
         43.46,12.55,-49.51,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.72,0.00,0.00,-0.74,0.00,-5.79)

    image(matrix(x), col=colorRampPalette(colors=c("#FF0000", "#FFFF00"))(length(x)))
    image(matrix(x), col=colorRampPalette(colors=c("#FF0000", "#FFFF00"))(length(unique(x))))
```

[image]
from the above comments, trying with `ggplot`

```
x<-c(4.80,1.09,33.40,0.00,11.63,1.86,2.22,-10.95,-3.09,0.00,2.38,0.00,
     43.46,12.55,-49.51,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.72,0.00,0.00,-0.74,0.00,-5.79)

df<-data.frame(x=seq_along(x), y=10, col=x)
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq_along(x), y=1, col=x), aes(x, y, color=col)) + geom_point(size=8)+
  scale_colour_gradient2(low="red", high="yellow", mid="white")+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"))
```

interesting, seems because of high +/- the one close to zero are not that different
[image]